# Email is not being sent via python

Tags: python, email

I have created this piece of code as a test run to send an email over python:

```
import smtplib
import random
import math
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ADMIN_EMAIL = email
ADMIN_PASS = password



def generate_ver_code():
    digs = "0123456789"
    code = ""
    for i in range(0, 6):
        code += digs[math.floor(random.random() * 10)]
    return code



def signup(forename, surname, email, occupation, dob, pass1, pass2, pass_match):
    ran_num = str(random.randint(0, 9999))
    if len(ran_num) >= 4:
        if len(ran_num) == 1:
            ran_num = "000" + str(ran_num)
        elif len(ran_num) == 2:
            ran_num = "00" + str(ran_num)
        elif len(ran_num) == 3:
            ran_num = "0" + str(ran_num)
        elif len(ran_num) == 4:
            ver_code = str(ran_num)
    username = ran_num + forename[:3] + surname[:3] + dob[:2]
    
    if pass1 == pass2:
        passw = pass1
        pass_match = True
    else:
        pass_match = False
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 5354)
    #home port = 5354
    #school port = 
    s.starttls()
    s.login(ADMIN_EMAIL, ADMIN_PASS)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=forename)
    msg['From']=ADMIN_EMAIL
    msg['To']=email
    msg['Subject']="Verify account: FAKtory Reset"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, '\nBefore you can continue to use your account please verify yur account and check if the credentials are correct:\nUsername: '+ username + '\nName: ' + forename + ' ' + surname + '\nOccupation: ' + occupation + '\nDoB: ' + dob + '\nPassword: ' + pass1 + '\nVerification Code: ' + ver_code + '\nIf any of the credentials are wrong please enter them again on our app.\nThank you,\nRegards,\nFaizan Ali Khan\nAdmin'))
    s.send_message(msg)
    del msg



pass_match = False
forename = str(input("Enter your forename: "))
surname = str(input("Enter your surname: "))
email = str(input("Enter your email: "))
occupation = str(input("Enter your occupation: "))
dob = str(input("Enter your date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY): "))
pass1 = str(input("Enter your password: "))
pass2 = str(input("Enter your password again: "))
print(signup(forename, surname, email, occupation, dob, pass1, pass2, pass_match))
```

Now whenever I run the code it goes fine for the inputs but when it comes to sending the email I get this error:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

How would you fix this error? I tried changing the port but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Your port looks wrong. smtp.google.com tls is port 587 (https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 5354)
```

The issue is this code snippet. According to the official [Gmail IMAP Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp) the outgoing port is either `465` or `587`:

> The outgoing SMTP server, `smtp.gmail.com`, requires TLS. Use port `465`, or port `587` if your client begins with plain text before issuing the STARTTLS command.